# Way to Big api response test (fastapi, pydantic)

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic

I'm using Fastapi and Pydantic in my app.

I'm looking for way to using Pydantic BaseModel Schemas for testing.

If I write pydantic Basemodel like this,

```
class Response(BaseModel):
    str_data1 : str,
    str_date2: str,
    int_data1: int,
    int_data2: int
```

and I want to test like this.

```
from fastapi import status
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from main import app
from schemas.schema import Response
client = TestClient(app)


def test_report():

   response = client.get("/")
   assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
   assert response.json() == Response //obviously this line is not working
```

the way to do this as hard coding but I dont want to do like this

```
def test_report():

   response = client.get("/")
   assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
   assert type(response.json()["str_data1"]) == str
   ...
```

If Response is really Big, How can I check type and key for response to using pydantic schemas?

Comment: Pydantic automatically convert types. If you set `r = R(str_data1 = 111, str_date2 = "2", int_data1 = 1, int_data2 = "3")` then `int_data2 = "3"` will be converted to int `3` and `str_data1 = 111` will be converted into `"111"`. Your check is meaningless it will be always `True` or `Pydantic` error will be raised before `assert` statement

Comment: @rzlvmp sorry to reply late! Yes I realized that i dont need to check data structure of response because I return pydantic schema class's object to client! thank you.